# SetEnv TZ vs date.timezone

Tags: apache, configuration, timezone, php

What is the difference between setting the timezone in Apache's **SetEnv TZ** (.htaccess) and PHP's **date.timezone** (php.ini)? I haven't been able to detect how **SetEnv TZ** gets used. I tried setting **SetEnv TZ** to one value and **date.timezone** to another timezone but only the latter, **date.timezone**, seems to have any effect on the web pages. I'm also wondering how Apache configuratoins and PHP configurations, for the same things, affect the server, such as which overwrites which.

Answer (score 3):

The URL http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php should give you the exact answer; in short (assuming a recent version of php > 5.4.0) it checks for the one set with date_default_timezone_set() within php and if not set, checks the value of  date.timezone in php.ini. If that one is unset - it gives up. So TZ is ignored.

Or in other words for > 5.4.0 the environment variable TZ is never consulted.

For 5.4.0 and before - it is consulted when no default/ini is set. See the above URL for exact order and details.

Comment: That's wonderful that PHP ignores Apache VirtualHost timezone env var. That means if I'm working with multiple PHP apps on my local Apache computer, and each app is meant to work with a data import with its own timezone which isn't PHP's, everything will be off unless I force it in the PHP code somewhere. Not the best idea if you need to make a commit to change timezones if server location is switching. Really weird restriction.