# Can I set a timezone for mod_rewrite time variables?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, timezone

I alread set the time zone in my .htaccess but seems it isn't working

```
SetEnv TZ Europe/Lisbon

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

My Time zone is -05h I want to change to 0h (Europe/Lisbon or Europe/London)

```
RewriteCond %{TIME}<^20131119231500$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ php/teste.php?time=%{TIME}&time_sec=%{TIME_SEC}&time_hour=%{TIME_HOUR}& [L]
```

Comment: Whose time zone do you want to change where? And re the second code snippet - would that not be much easier to do in the PHP file rather than the htaccess file?

Comment: This might be helpful: [SetEnv TZ vs date.timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501242/setenv-tz-vs-date-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that -5 or 0 are *time zone offsets*, while `Europe/Lisbon` and `Europe/London` are *time zones*.  There is a huge difference.

In particular, `Europe/London` is only at 0 offset in the winter.  In the summer, it is at the +1 offset.  You probably want to just use the `UTC` time zone, which is 0 all year long.

You may want to review the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section "Time Zone != Offset"

And then, I'm not sure why you are trying to change this via .htaccess.  If you are using PHP, then change it either in the [`date.timezone` setting in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone), or by a call to [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in your PHP code.

For example:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```